# ruby equivalent of php snoopy

Tags: php, ruby, snoopy

Is there a Ruby equivalent for [PHP Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)? Snoopy is a PHP class that provides the functionality of a web-browser.

Comment: The answer is mechanize although they're not equivalent because mechanize is about 100x better :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). [Some examples here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html).

Comment: it could also works for ajax forms right? for example

    `<input type='text' id='x' /><input type='button' onclick='doSend()' /><script> function doSend() { var x = $('#x').val(); $.post('',{x:x},function(res){ alert(res) }); } </script>`

Comment: Since it doesnt have a js engine the functionality maybe limited.